# Is it possible to have static type declarations for function input arguments in Python3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, nameerror

This is a syntax I see in Python3 code skeletons on leetcode.com. Note the type declarations of the function input arguments (or at least I think they're type declarations, never seen it before). `nums` must be a `List` of `int`, and `s` must be an `int`.

```
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], S: int) -> int:
        pass
```

If I run that function inside the environment on leetcode.com, it exits without error. However, if I run the same code in my own Python 3.7.3 environment, I get a NameError.

> ```
> def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], S: int) -> int: NameError: name 'List' is not defined
> ```

What is wrong? Is the syntax on leetcode.com even real Python?

Comment: You can import `List` from the `typing` module.

Comment: The technical term is *function annotation*, one use (and the only officially supported use) of which is for type hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is real syntax, officially used since 3.7 I believe.

The `List` used in this static typing is imported from the `typing` module.

You can read more about it in [PEP-484: Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) or in the [`typing` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Comment: Ah! Invisible imports on leetcode.com had me fooled.